# Couldn't get File Lock

Tags: java, datastage, ibm-infosphere

In a datastage parallel job we are getting a warning

> user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock

**Observations :** The error is coming up only for one job, and for only one set of file (large in size 400 000 to 500 000 records) in that job.
Sometimes it is observing in other jobs as well, But many jobs under the same platform is working fine.

[IBM Doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-infosphere-datastage-job-using-hierarchichal-stage-gets-multiple-warnings-0-couldnt-flush-user-prefs-javautilprefsbackingstoreexception-couldnt-get-file-lock)

As per the above IBM doc we set the correct value for JAVA_HOME variable, But still the issue persists.

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue, there are some suggestions in this link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/starting-websphere-application-server-gives-warning-message-could-not-lock-user-prefs

One other thing to check is that there is free disk space on the failing system.

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood